# Mediatr Notifications on ViewModel in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mediatr

While implementing a WPF Application I stumbled on the problem that my application needs some global data in every ViewModel. However some of the ViewModels only need reading access while other need read/write access for this Field. At First I stumbled upon the Microsoft Idea of a SessionContext like so:

```
public class SessionContext
    {
        #region Public Members
        public static string UserName { get; set; }
        public static string Role { get; set; }

        public static Teacher CurrentTeacher { get; set; }
        public static Parent CurrentParent { get; set; }
        public static LocalStudent CurrentStudent { get; set; }

        public static List<LocalGrade> CurrentGrades { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public static void Logon(string userName, string role)
        {
            UserName = userName;
            Role = role;
        }

        public static void Logoff()
        {
            UserName = "";
            Role = "";
            CurrentStudent = null;
            CurrentTeacher = null;
            CurrentParent = null;
        }
        #endregion
}
```

This isn't (in my Opinion at least) nicely testable and it gets problematic in case my global data grows (A think that could likely happen in this application).
The next thing I found was the implementation of a Mediator/the Mediator Pattern from this [link](https://www.norberteder.com/lose-kommunikation-zwischen-viewmodels/). I liked the Idea of the Design Norbert is going here and thought about implementing something similar for my project. However in this project I am already using the impressive Mediatr Nuget Package and that is also a Mediator implementation. So I thought "Why reinvent the Wheel" if I could just use a nice and well tested Mediator. But here starts my real Question: In case of sending changes to the global data by other ViewModels to my Readonly ViewModels I would use Notifications. That means:

```
public class ReadOnlyViewModel : NotificationHandler<Notification>
{
   //some Member

    //global Data
    public string Username {get; private set;}

    public async Task Handle(Notification notification, CancellationToken     token) 
    {
        Username = notification.Username;
    }

}
```

The Question(s) now: 
1. Is this a good Practice for using MVVM (It's just a Feeling that doing this is wrong because it feels like exposing Business Logic in the ViewModel)
2. Is there a better way to seperate this so that my Viewmodel doesn't need to inherit 5 to 6 different NotificationHandlers<,>?

**Update:**
As Clarification to what I want to achieve here:
My Goal is to implement a wpf application that manages some Global Data (lets say a Username as mentioned above) for one of its Window. That means because i am using a DI Container (and because of what kind of data it is) that I have to declare the Service @mm8 proposed as a Singleton. That however is a little bit problematic in case (and I have that case) I need to open a new Window that needs different global data at this time. That would mean that I either need to change the lifetime to something like "kind of scoped" or (breaking the single Responsibility of the class) by adding more fields for different Purposes or I create n Services for the n possible Windows I maybe need to open. To the first Idea of splitting the Service: I would like to because that would mitigate all the above mentioned problems but that would make the sharing of Data problematic because I don't know a reliable way to communicate this global data from the Writeservice to the readservice while something async or parallell running is happening in a Background Thread that could trigger the writeservice to update it's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a shared service that you inject your view models with. It can for example implement two interfaces, one for write operations and one for read operations only, e.g.:

```
public interface IReadDataService
{
    object Read();
}

public interface IWriteDataService : IReadDataService
{
    void Write();
}

public class GlobalDataService : IReadDataService, IWriteDataService
{
    public object Read()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You would then inject the view models that should have write access with a `IWriteDataService` (and the other ones with a `IReadDataService`):

```
public ViewModel(IWriteDataService dataService) { ... }
```

This solution both makes the code easy to understand and easy to test.

Comment: Wouldn't that allow the nifty Developer to just cast an IWriteDataService to an GlobalDataservice giving him both Methods? And is the Controll of the Lifetime of this Object (especially if you sometimes need two of those) kind of impossible?

Comment: @Brezelmann: Given the above *sample* implementation, yes. If you don't want this, you could just create two separate services. I don't understand your question about the lifetime. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I updated my Question to give you a better idea on what is going on and where I am having trouble with.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. If the read service has a dependency on the write service or vice versa, you could just inject it with a reference to the other service. And how to write thread-safe code is way out of the scope of your original question.

Comment: The Project is trying to be a bridge between many Webservices used by my Company. That means I have arround 600 Fields that I need in a somewhat global state. This "global State" changes in case the user inputs some state while opening a new Window. The Problem here is that, I sometimes need to retain the old values and sometimes not. Or that sometimes the same fields can be filled with different Data Sets. That makes the service Idea of yours quite hard to use because these informations that a field is needed twice with different values is only available at runtime and never at compilation.

Comment: that is why I liked the Idea of a Mediatr in the first place. I could use one to just fire and forget as many Notifications with global state in it and forget if two ViewModels needed the same field set with different values or something. However what i didn't like with the Mediatr was the Idea of having my ViewModel implement as many INotificationHandlers as I needed Notifications. And thats my main Question. Is there a better way to Notifiy my ViewModels without them implementing 20 different INotificationHandler<T>? or is this my only Option?

Comment: @Brezelmann: You could use an event aggregator but you will still need to subscribe to and handle 20 different events.

Comment: Ah okay so no matter what I'' choose I still have to go the long way :(. Thanks for the Help, I appreciate it.